# How to secure my multi tenant webapp that is running on Azure

Tags: active-directory, wif, adfs, acs, azure-active-directory

I'm struggling with my MVC5 webapp that is hosted on Azure. I need to secure it (of course) but I don't want to let the users create yet another account, with another password they can forget.

So I've looked into Azure Access Control (ACS). It looks nice, but the Identity Providers provided are very limited. I'm missing LinkedIn as an IP for example. Therefore a lot of users will have to create a new account with a company emailaddress. Facebook user typically use their private emailaddress.

So Azure Active Directory looks fine. You can federate with a local Active Directory. But after diving into it, it seems that you cannot create a tenant from you code. So the user must first do thing in the Azure portal, and that is confusing and I want to make things as easy as possible.

What do I need:

- authentications of users without storing their password myself
- creation of new users by code
- be able to federate to a customer's Active Directory (on premise or Azure Active Directory)
- user must be able to use whatever emailaddress they're using

Do you have good suggestions to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you looking at many different domains or not that many clients?

Comment: It must be suited for many different domains.

Comment: If the requirement is to use there corporate email and your client is the corporate behind it then I would say you are on the right lines with Azure AD.  As you have worked out though it needs configured and you may find that not all clients have the ability to connect with third parties.  Anything else is a compromise which you have stated you don't want.  You could probably automate much of the setup but there will always be an intervention with fully synced AD.You might find it acceptable to use the corp email address but with a different password, it keeps it away from the personal domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage users in AAD using the [Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx).

Using DirSync or AADSync, you can propagate your on-premise users to AAD.

User will have to logon on-premise and again in the cloud but using the same credentials. (Same Sign On).

Adding ADFS to the mix gives you SSO. (Single Sign On).

Typically, only the corporate domain can be used for email address.

For other applications, look at: [Azure Active Directory applications](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/active-directory/?term=face).